# Take 10 numbers from the right to calculate a key

Tags: excel, vba

I have these two codes, they calculate the keys of a bank account number, by I want to modify them so that the code would take 10 numbers from the right to calculate the corresponding key.
For example if the number is : 6465981, the code will take it all into consideration since it’s 7 numbers long.
If the number is 007999990006465981, it will take 0006465981 to calculate the key.
The two codes are :

```
Public Function CCP(Cle_CCP As String) As String

CCP = Len(Cle_CCP)
CCP = (10 - CCP)
For i = 1 To CCP
M = M & "0"
Next
CCP = M & Cle_CCP
M1 = Mid(CCP, 1, 1) * 13
M2 = Mid(CCP, 2, 1) * 12
M3 = Mid(CCP, 3, 1) * 11
M4 = Mid(CCP, 4, 1) * 10
M5 = Mid(CCP, 5, 1) * 9
M6 = Mid(CCP, 6, 1) * 8
M7 = Mid(CCP, 7, 1) * 7
M8 = Mid(CCP, 8, 1) * 6
M9 = Mid(CCP, 9, 1) * 5
M10 = Mid(CCP, 10, 1) * 4
CCP = M1 + M2 + M3 + M4 + M5 + M6 + M7 + M8 + M9 + M10

If CCP < 10 Then
   CCP = "0" & CCP
Else
   CCP = CCP
End If

CCP = Right(CCP, 2)

End Function

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Public Function RIP(Cle_RIP As String) As String

If Cle_RIP = "" Then
   Cle_RIP = 0
End If

RIP = Cle_RIP * 100
RIP = RIP - 97 * Int(RIP / 97)
RIP = RIP + 85

If RIP < 97 Then
   RIP = RIP + 97
Else
   RIP = RIP
End If

RIP = RIP - 97
RIP = 97 - RIP

If RIP < 10 Then
   RIP = "0" & RIP
Else
   RIP = RIP
End If
End Function
```

Comment: What problem are facing right now? It seem for loop making it 10 digit already. You can use `M=RIGHT("0000000000"&Cle_CCP,10)` to make it always 10 digit from right.

Comment: Harun24hr
 For example, if i type 90006465981, the code will take just 0006465981 to calculate the key, which is 32 or 77, by the code gives me 52 and 67 instead

Comment: Let give a try to my answer and feedback your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please give a try to the following codes-

```
Public Function CCP(Cle_CCP As String) As String

CCP = Len(Cle_CCP)
CCP = (10 - CCP)

'For i = 1 To CCP
'M = M & "0"
'Next

    CCP = Right("0000000000" & Cle_CCP, 10)
    M1 = Mid(CCP, 1, 1) * 13
    M2 = Mid(CCP, 2, 1) * 12
    M3 = Mid(CCP, 3, 1) * 11
    M4 = Mid(CCP, 4, 1) * 10
    M5 = Mid(CCP, 5, 1) * 9
    M6 = Mid(CCP, 6, 1) * 8
    M7 = Mid(CCP, 7, 1) * 7
    M8 = Mid(CCP, 8, 1) * 6
    M9 = Mid(CCP, 9, 1) * 5
    M10 = Mid(CCP, 10, 1) * 4
    CCP = M1 + M2 + M3 + M4 + M5 + M6 + M7 + M8 + M9 + M10

    If CCP < 10 Then
       CCP = "0" & CCP
    Else
       CCP = CCP
    End If

CCP = Right(CCP, 2)

End Function
```

Comment: If you need 10 digit in case of `RIP` function then use same logic.